# AJAX response type. I can't use JSON. Any alternatives?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to POST form values to a PHP page and expect an AJAX response.

I normally do this with JSON but I can't use JSON in current situation. The response is always text/html but I need to do something like this:

```
if(response.status == 'success')
     //success codes
else
     //error codes
```

How can I do this? Only by hacking returned HTML response and regexing for "success" word anywhere?

PS. No XML/YML either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

short answer yes.

You could simply use(indestead of regex)

```
function(data) {
 if(data.indexOf("success") != -1)
   {
   alert("we have something to work with!");
   }
 }
```

Comment: possible solution, i would still grep out the status to also react on the errors accordingly.

Comment: yes, I would suggest something like that, but that wasn't the question ;-). You could use for example `:` as a delimeter and do `data.split(':');` to get an array of values, as long as you make for yourself clear which data will be at which position.

Comment: I think I have to google about indexOf function. :) [Edit: Looks very easy. It's probably the solution I'll go with.]

Answer (score 0):

Just echo out a text.

```
 echo "success";
```

Then javascript.

```
 if(data === 'success')
 // do your thang
```

Comment: "The response is always text/html"

Comment: The OP said the response is HTML so I guess your solution is not applicable.

Comment: Doesn't that apply to text too? text/html can have html code, but doesn't have to, as far as I understand it.

Comment: the `success` will be embedded somewhere in the string, so a plain comparison will never work.